# Formula interpretation to php

Tags: php

I have a problem. How can I convert this formula `(t)^1.5` to php code.

Thank you.

Comment: See the [`pow()`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php) function.

Answer (score 4):

PHP `pow();` should be able to do it. Thus, it would turn out as `pow($variable_representing_t, 1.5);`

For more information, see here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php

Answer (score 1):

Does the caret represent a *power of*? If so, then `pow(t,1.5);`